# function definition not working in .bashrc

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, bashrc

```bsh
submit () {
    kaggle c submit -f $@ -m MSG h-and-m-personalized-fashion-recommendations;
}
```

I want to use the above function as shorthand for submitting files to kaggle competitions by typing `submit FILE`. I'm having problems setting it up being a Bash noob. The function works perfectly when i put it in a testing script `test.sh` and run that, but when I put it in `.bashrc` and `source .bashrc` I get the following error:

```
bash: .bashrc: line 148: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: .bashrc: line 148: `submit () {'
```

It's not an error from something else in my code in disguise since when I remove only that functions (those three lines without touching any other lines), `source .bashrc` no longer throws errors.

And again, having it in a separate script and running that with `bash test.sh` works perfectly so there is no syntax error. Copied and pasted the  function from `test.sh` to `.bashrc`, too, so it's the exact same function in both.

Comment: Please include your entire `~/.bashrc` in your question - I suspect there is some error there still.

Comment: @ArturMeinild Added it to the question.

Comment: @Terrance Tried removing the space. Doesn't help. Same exact error.

Comment: What happens if you just copy paste the `submit () {...}` lines to your terminal? For me, I get no error.

Comment: @pLumo When I literally copy and paste the three lines it obviously breaks the function into three separate commands at each of the newlines. When I reformat the definition into the one-liner `submit () { kaggle c submit -f $@ -m MSG h-and-m-personalized-fashion-recommendations; }` I get `bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('`

Comment: I figured the problem out. The name is the issue. If I change it to `ksubmit` it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the name. Simply changing `submit` to `ksubmit` fixes the issue. I previously had an alias called submit which may have caused a clash of sorts where bash substituted it instead of realising it's a function definition. I reproduced the issue by removing `ksubmit` from .bashrc and adding `alias ksubmit="kaggle c list"`. Then `source`ing `.bashrc`. Followed by, in the same shell, removing the alias definition from .bashrc and adding the `ksubmit` function definition again, then sourcing that. Gives the syntax error from above. Simply needed to unalias or start a new shell.

Simple issue, but hard to debug because the error message doesn't really point you to the problem when you're unexperienced.